# How to get the full resolution in windowed mode?

Tags: technical-issues, dishonored

When running Dishonored in windowed mode it does not use the full selected resolution - e.g. when I select 1920x1200 (which is also my native resolution) the window does not span the full width of my screen. Since I usually use GameCompanion to convert full-size windows to fake fullscreen (like in WoW etc.) this is annoying as it doesn't work - most likely due to the fact that the window is too small.

So I wonder if there's a way (such as an INI tweak) to make the game window use the full resolution I selected in the options.

Comment: Try disabling game companion before you play. I don't know what that is, but it sounds like that's causing the issues.

Comment: It's not. The issue is unrelated to it - it wasn't even running when I initially set window mode and the resolution.

Comment: And the -noborder option doesn't work with this game.  I couldn't find any good solution for this issue, sorry.